# How many dB can the sound pressure level be amplified by installing a horn on the compression driver?

Tags: acoustics

I bought a 113dB compression driver with good sensitivity, but it still does not reach the required level. I am trying to increase the sound pressure level to the maximum using the horn, but I want to know what the limit is.

Answer (score 2):

All compression driver units require a horn for proper operation because their radiation resistance without a horn is very low. Their rated SPL assumes the use of a theoretically perfect horn.

This horn will also focus the radiated sound into a beam. For use in a small room, you'll need a beam angle of 90 degrees so the horn can be heard throughout the room. Outdoors, you'll need a *long-throw* horn to form a beam of between 30 and 45 degrees.

Note that if you cut the beam angle in half, the on-axis SPL level will be increased by about +3dB, but this trick requires the use of a large and precisely manufactured horn.